# Windows compatibility workaround for AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute EXIT_CODE

Tags: python, windows, attributeerror, raise

When calling `quit(os.EX_CONFIG)` on Windows, it gives `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'EX_CONFIG'` since `os.EX_CONFIG` is not compatibile with Windows (like other os's exit codes).

Is there a workaround to leave it exit with the selected code on Unix, but not raise AttributeError on unsupported systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a condition on the platform like the following one:

```py
if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    quit(os.EX_CONFIG)  # `os.EX_CONFIG` is only compatible with Linux
else:
    quit()
```